# Is there a vCalendar microformat validator/sanity checker?

Tags: html, validation, microformats, vcalendar

I just put up a new calendar in the vCalendar microformat on one of my websites. However, I don't know how I can check if the format is valid and the dates are right. Apparently, I can't import it directly to Google Calendar.

Is there an easy way to transform vCalendar data into a real calendar easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried out [Optimus](http://microformatique.com/optimus/) to validate the page and see if it can transform the data into XML or JSON?

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful tool. I'm glad something can read my microformat!

Comment: Optimus link is broken :(

Answer (score 1):

http://hcard.geekhood.net/

Answer (score 0):

[H2VX — Events Conversion Service: hCalendar to iCalendar](http://h2vx.com/ics/)

Answer (score 0):

A Firefox add-on called [Operator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4106) was recommended to me for checking Microformats.

This being said, it doesn't seem to do a lot of validation (if such a thing is even possible with Microformats).